# AES Java to Python

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes

This is an AES encryption code I've gotten from a Java source. This bugs me, as the `Cipher` itself doesn't use any initial vector in it's initialization - thus I can't seem to to the same thing in Python. Can anyone with a Java background help me understand what this actually does?

```
byte key[] = {0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xB4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
byte[] myIv = {70, 114, 122, 82, 70, 114, 122, 82, 70, 114, 122, 82, 70, 114, 122, 82}
byte[] newIv = cipher.doFinal(myIv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses `"AES"` as algorithm string, which (indeed) resolves to `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`. It seems you can use `AES.MODE_ECB` in python using PyCrypto, so it should be no problem replicating that. You may have to implement PKCS#7 padding/unpadding yourself though (or use [one of the many examples on the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205319/589259)). You would not need any IV because ECB doesn't use an IV.

As why a static key is used and why a static IV is being encrypted (with padding) is unknown to me. That can only be clarified by the author of the code. It certainly does not follow best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Java has providers which implement some schemes. A scheme is chosen from a string, in your case `Cipher.getInstance("AES")`. Since it is not possible to run plain AES in Java, it selects some defaults to make it a complete scheme.

It is necessary to determine the mode of operation and optionally the padding mode. Most providers in Java default to `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"` when they see `"AES"`.

Now for `byte[] newIv = cipher.doFinal(myIv)`. This line encrypts the plaintext (`myIv`) with AES in ECB mode and applies PKCS#7 padding. ECB mode doesn't use an IV, so this is bad variable naming, because `myIv` is not an IV for the encryption.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12525165) is a post that shows how padding and unpadding can be done.