# AES: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length

Tags: python, aes

I want to make a script to decrypt my filess, but when I try to run my script then show me this message , how can I fix it?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:\bug_bounty\decrypt.py",
>   line 46, in    File "F:\bug_bounty\decrypt.py", line 24, in
>   decrypt   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py", line 295,
>   in decrypt
>       return self._cipher.decrypt(ciphertext) ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os
import random
import sys


def decrypt(key, filename):
    outFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename),
                           os.path.basename(filename[11:]))
    chunksize = 64 * 1024
    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        filesize = infile.read(16)
        IV = infile.read(16)

        decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

        with open(outFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break

                outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))

            outfile.truncate(int(filesize))


def allfiles():
    allFiles = []
    for (root, subfiles, files) in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        for names in files:
            allFiles.append(os.path.join(root, names))

    return allFiles


password = 'M4st3rRul3zs'
files = allfiles();
for filename in files:
    if os.path.basename(filename).startswith("(encrypted)"):
       print "%s is already encrypted" %filename
       pass

    else:  
        decrypt(SHA256.new(password).digest(), filename)
        print "Done decrypting %s" %filename
        """os.remove(filename)"""
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14205319/3527520 may be helpful

Comment: how did you solve this

Answer (score 7):

Here is the small trick you could use while encrypting the data if your data size is **not large**.

```
plaintext = "some text"
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(plaintext*16)
```

This will ensure that your input data is a multiple of 16. And of course, you would like to get the original data back when decrypting.

```
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decrypttext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
decrypttext = decrypttext[0:len(plaintext)]
```

Now, `decrpyttext` has your original plaintext.

Comment: Or, you could also use `decrpyttext = decrpyttext[0: len(decrpyttext)//16]`

Answer (score 5):

From [Crypto++ wiki](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

> The block size is determined by AES::BLOCKSIZE. For AES, this is
>   always 16 bytes

AES is a block cipher, it works on 16-byte (128-bit) blocks. It can't work with data **smaller or bigger than 16 bytes**. Smaller data needs to be **padded** until they're 16 bytes, and larger data needs to be split into 16-byte blocks.

Also there are algorithms that help you achieve just that (work on data larger than the cipher's block size), they're called [block cipher modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

Have a look at this [How to encrypt more than 16 bytes using AES?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52111/how-to-encrypt-more-than-16-bytes-using-aes)

Answer (score 2):

> ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length

That is because [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) works with blocks of 128 bits (16 chars). You can consider adding [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) to fix this.

Comment: in code how should be? 
filesize = infile.read(16)
        IV = infile.read(16)

        decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

Comment: @Aron Imperial google 'pkcs7 padding' or 'zero padding' they're both quite easy to implement

Answer (score 1):

AES works with blocks of 16 chars. This how you can add extra padding

```
import random
import string
```

```py
plaintext = "Encrypt me"
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

while len(bytes(plaintext, encoding='utf-8')) % 16 != 0:
     plaintext = plaintext + random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(plaintext)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.