# Node.js - Set padding in crypto module

Tags: node.js, cryptography, node-crypto

I've been looking over the docs for the [crypto module](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) in Node, and I'm trying to figure out how to set the padding when doing symmetric encryption. I'm trying to use AES-128-ECB, with PKCS5 padding.

I can't see anywhere that it allows you to specify padding. I would certainly hope this is possible to do using this library. How can I specify padding for symmetric encryption in the crypto module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_auto_padding_true

When you disable auto-padding, you can write any padding you wish by simply writing to `cipher` (which is a stream).

Comment: Or in other words, if you leave auto-padding enabled, the plaintext will be PKCS#5 padded automatically.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful, thanks! How would I write the correct padding to the string? I'm not super good with cryptography, so writing that correctly is difficult to know how to do.

Comment: @ntoskrnl since in iOS the default padding is PKCS#7 and can not be changed, so how to set padding to PKCS#7 in node.js?

Comment: @Veelian Yeah I did, but that was to use PKCS5 padding in Node, which is what I needed. I'm not sure how to set it to PKCS7.

Comment: @dsw88 PKCS#5 padding is the same as PKCS#7 padding.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that, thanks! I'm not super familiar with padding schemes, or other encryption details very much for that matter.

Comment: for block-size 128-bit, there are no difference between PKCS#5 and PKCS#7.