# Encrypting ByteArray using AES in Javascript

Tags: javascript, aes

I have been trying encrypt an array of bytes using AES in JavaScript but I am experiencing some troubles with that.
This is my code in Java and I can't reach the same result in JavaScript.
Can someone helping me? I've tryed using CriptoJs, Forge-Node, AES-js but none of the worked fine.

```
public static byte[] Cipher() throws Exception {
    byte[] msgCifrada = null;
    byte[] keyBytes = [85, -9, -79, -24, -80, 87, -3, 73, 87, -75, -120, 125, 90, -124, 109, -102];
    byte[] dados = [-88, -93, 5, -78, -116, 36, -49, -11, 106, 111, 110, 97, 116, 104, 97, 115, 46, 115, 105, 108, 118, 97];

    try {
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        msgCifrada = c.doFinal(dados);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
        throw new Exception("Chave simétrica inválida.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Erro na cifragem da mensagem: "+ .getMessage());
    }
    return msgCifrada;
}
```

The result in Java is that ByteArray:

[-90, 91, 44, 29, -113, 116, -1, -29, 42, 47, 122, -117, -12, -12, -49, -94, 59, -50, 110, 115, 105, -21, 80, 93, -15, 13, 71, -108, 23, -80, 56, -96]

Thank you!

Comment: You may consider looking at this thread. If it answers your query, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698721/encrypt-in-node-and-decrypt-in-java# I'm removing my answer as it doesn't answer your particular question.

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu Thanks. This article shows me a way to encrypt and obtain the same result as my Java Code.