# Decrypting AES256 with node.js returns wrong final block length

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, aes

Using this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ericchen/3081970) I was able to successfully decrypt AES256 in Node.js 0.8.7.  Then when I upgraded to Node.js 0.10.24, I now see this error:

> TypeError: error:0606506D:digital envelope
>   routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   at Decipheriv.Cipher.final (crypto.js:292:27)

Here is the decrypt code from the Gist (shown here for convenience):

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var AESCrypt = {};

AESCrypt.decrypt = function(cryptkey, iv, encryptdata) {
encryptdata = new Buffer(encryptdata, 'base64').toString('binary');

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', cryptkey, iv),
decoded = decipher.update(encryptdata);

decoded += decipher.final();
return decoded;
}

AESCrypt.encrypt = function(cryptkey, iv, cleardata) {
var encipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', cryptkey, iv),
encryptdata = encipher.update(cleardata);

encryptdata += encipher.final();
encode_encryptdata = new Buffer(encryptdata, 'binary').toString('base64');
return encode_encryptdata;
}

var cryptkey = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('Nixnogen').digest(),
iv = 'a2xhcgAAAAAAAAAA',
buf = "Here is some data for the encrypt", // 32 chars
enc = AESCrypt.encrypt(cryptkey, iv, buf);
var dec = AESCrypt.decrypt(cryptkey, iv, enc);

console.warn("encrypt length: ", enc.length);
console.warn("encrypt in Base64:", enc);
console.warn("decrypt all: " + dec);
```

Comment: I'm also facing a similar issue. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038267/getting-error-wrong-final-block-length-while-decyrpting-aes256

Comment: Here are some similar questions and answers: [Nodejs decrypt using crypto error wrong final block length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23111388/608639), [Getting error wrong final block length while decrypting AES256](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32038267/608639), [Decrypt file in Node.js encrypted using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44482151/608639), [How to decipher string in node.js which is encrypted in crypto.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28359128/608639), [What's wrong with node.js crypto decipher?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12219499/608639)

Comment: It helps me `decipher.setAutoPadding(false);`   By default node uses PKCS padding but other langauges C++, Python not using this padding.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, so there was a change to Crypto in the switch from 0.8 to 0.10 [Crypto methods return Buffer objects by default, rather than binary-encoded strings](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Api-changes-between-v0.8-and-v0.10)

This means the above code needs to specify encodings.

These four lines:

```
decoded = decipher.update(encryptdata);
decoded += decipher.final();
encryptdata = encipher.update(cleardata);
encryptdata += encipher.final();
```

Are changed to:

```
decoded = decipher.update(encryptdata, 'binary', 'utf8');
decoded += decipher.final('utf8');
encryptdata = encipher.update(cleardata, 'utf8', 'binary');
encryptdata += encipher.final('binary');
```

This worked for me, but I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: Dude you saved me so much time.  Works like a charm!

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but I'm using a pipeline (passing the decipher variable to `pipe` on the file) to avoid issues with needing the entire file in memory.  Any idea what to do in that case?

Comment: We had this issue with a Heroku app that didn't have an "engines" attribute in the package.json. The version was updated on a deploy without us catching the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael I am Facing the same using pipeline ... Any solution??

Comment: can you help me here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550132/node-js-encrypt-and-decrypt-file?noredirect=1#comment92040944_52550132]

Comment: I was getting the same error as mentioned in the question. I looked at the code and I found that I was trying to decrypt without encrypting the data.

Comment: Can you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68287507/decrypting-selling-partner-api-reports

Answer (score 14):

As your answer states, those functions work with Buffers now unless you specify an encoding. That said, you'd be better off avoiding `binary` encoded strings entirely and treat everything as Buffers until you strictly need a string for something. This way you can also use your encryption helpers to process non-text content.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var AESCrypt = {};

AESCrypt.decrypt = function(cryptkey, iv, encryptdata) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', cryptkey, iv);
    return Buffer.concat([
        decipher.update(encryptdata),
        decipher.final()
    ]);
}

AESCrypt.encrypt = function(cryptkey, iv, cleardata) {
    var encipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', cryptkey, iv);
    return Buffer.concat([
        encipher.update(cleardata),
        encipher.final()
    ]);
}

var cryptkey = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('Nixnogen').digest(),
iv = new Buffer('a2xhcgAAAAAAAAAA'),
buf = new Buffer("Here is some data for the encrypt"), // 32 chars
enc = AESCrypt.encrypt(cryptkey, iv, buf);
var dec = AESCrypt.decrypt(cryptkey, iv, enc);

console.warn("encrypt length: ", enc.length);
console.warn("encrypt in Base64:", enc.toString('base64'));
console.warn("decrypt all: " + dec.toString('utf8'));
```

Comment: I'm also facing a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038267/getting-error-wrong-final-block-length-while-decyrpting-aes256 Take a look at it and give your valuable inputs

Comment: Is it possible to encrypt and decrypt the same field in different files? i keep getting this error `Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`

Comment: @kd12345 Please post a new question.

Answer (score 6):

My issue was that the string I was passing to my decrypt function was empty. I built in a check for empty strings and I did not receive the message again.

```
decrypt: function(text){
                if(text.length == 0){
                    return text;
                }
                return this.decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8') + this.decipher.final('utf8');
            }
```